# change date format from Y-m-d to d-m-Y

Tags: php, sql, date, format

based on this code :

```
$tarikh = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tarikh']);
    $tarikh = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['tarikh']));
```

can someone show me to convert the format from Y-m-d to d-m-Y format ? thanks

Comment: `$tarikh = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST['tarikh']));`

Comment: @itachi already done that but result in 0000-00-00 in database

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$tarikh = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tarikh']);
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $tarikh);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: $tarikh = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tarikh']);
  $myDateTime = date('Y-m-d', $tarikh);
  $newDateString = $myDateTime->date('d-m-Y');

it shown this notice :

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistem_laporan\tambah_laporan.php on line 208

Fatal error: Call to a member function date() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistem_laporan\tambah_laporan.php on line 209

Comment: I feel your date in `$_POST['tarikh']` is not valid date, please print `$tarikh` to check exactly what is coming from the `$_POST['tarikh']`